# Python - BeautifulSoup - Iterating through findall by specific elements in list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to the world of web scraping so am looking for some guidance to an issue I've been trying to resolve for a few hours.

I'm trying to loop through a table looking structure (it's not an actual table though) and have used findall to bring back all the details of a certain tag.

The challenge I have is that every element of the "table" has the same class name "final-leaderboard__content" so I'm left with a huge list so I want to iterate through and retrieve the details for so I can create a csv/excel with the details.  This is the code below

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

TournamentURL = "https://www.theopen.com/previous-opens/19th-open-st-andrews-1879/"
TournamentResponse = requests.get(TournamentURL)
TournamentData = TournamentResponse.text
TournamentSoup = BeautifulSoup(TournamentData, 'html.parser')

RowContents = TournamentSoup.findAll("div", {"class": "final-leaderboard__content"})
     for RowContent in RowContents:
```

---

The result is something like this and I can't work out the best way without there being any explicit tag/id to know that item 0,8,16 etc is the Player Name, item 1,9,17 is the Finish etc etc

```
[0] - Name
[1] - Finish
[2] - R1
[3] - R2
[4] - R3
[5] - R4
[6] - Total
[7] - Par
[8] - Name (The second Name)
[9] - Finish (The second Finish) 
etc
etc
```

I've tried splice, modulo and various other variants of the same but can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that this is *indeed* a kind of tabular data and grab all `divs` that represent a row, split it by a number of columns, and there's your data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

url = "https://www.theopen.com/previous-opens/19th-open-st-andrews-1879/#leaderboard"
page = requests.get(url).content

leaderboard = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all("div", {"class": "final-leaderboard__content"})

column_count = 8
split_by_columns = [
    leaderboard[i:i+column_count] for i in range(0, len(leaderboard), column_count)
]

table = [[i.getText(strip=True) for i in row] for row in split_by_columns]
print(tabulate(table[1:], headers=table[0]))
```

Output:

```
Name                             Finish    R1    R2  R3    R4      Total  Par
-----------------------------  --------  ----  ----  ----  ----  -------  -----
Jamie ANDERSONChampion Golfer         1    84    85  -     -         169  M/C
Andrew KIRKALDY                       2    86    86  -     -         172  M/C
Jamie ALLAN                           2    88    84  -     -         172  M/C
George  PAXTON                        4    89    85  -     -         174  M/C
Tom KIDD                              5    87    88  -     -         175  M/C
Bob FERGUSON                          6    89    87  -     -         176  M/C
J.O.F. MORRIS                         7    92    87  -     -         179  M/C
Jack KIRKALDY                         8    92    89  -     -         181  M/C
James RENNIE                          8    93    88  -     -         181  M/C
Willie FERNIE                         8    92    89  -     -         181  M/C
David AYTON                          11    95    89  -     -         184  M/C
Henry LAMB                           11    91    93  -     -         184  M/C
Tom ARUNDEL                          11    95    89  -     -         184  M/C
Tom MORRIS SR                        14    92    93  -     -         185  M/C
William DOLEMAN                      14    91    94  -     -         185  M/C
Robert KINSMAN                       14    88    97  -     -         185  M/C
Bob MARTIN                           17    93    93  -     -         186  M/C
Ben SAYERS                           18    92    95  -     -         187  M/C
David ANDERSON SR                    19    94    94  -     -         188  M/C
David CORSTORPHINE                   20    93    96  -     -         189  M/C
Tom DUNN                             20    90    99  -     -         189  M/C
Peter PAXTON                         20    99    90  -     -         189  M/C
[A] SMITH                            20    94    95  -     -         189  M/C
D. GRANT                             20    95    94  -     -         189  M/C
Bob DOW                              20    95    94  -     -         189  M/C
Walter GOURLAY                       20    92    97  -     -         189  M/C
A.W. SMITH                           27    91    99  -     -         190  M/C
Douglas Argyll ROBERTSON             27    97    93  -     -         190  M/C
Robert ARMIT                         29    95    96  -     -         191  M/C
George  STRATH                       29    97    94  -     -         191  M/C
J.H. BLACKWELL                       31    96    96  -     -         192  M/C
Tom MANZIE                           32    96    97  -     -         193  M/C
George LOWE                          33    94   100  -     -         194  M/C
G. HONEYMAN                          33    97    97  -     -         194  M/C
James FENTON                         35    99    97  -     -         196  M/C
Robert TAIT                          35    99    97  -     -         196  M/C
Bob KIRK                             37    99    98  -     -         197  M/C
Rev. D. LUNDIE                       37    98    99  -     -         197  M/C
Fitz BOOTHBY                         39    96   102  -     -         198  M/C
J. Thomson WHITE                     40   102    99  -     -         201  M/C
James KIRK                           41   105    97  -     -         202  M/C
W.H. GOFF                            42   105    99  -     -         204  M/C
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_row(row):
    for div in row.find_all("div", {"class": "final-leaderboard__content"}):
        yield div.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ')


url = "https://www.theopen.com/previous-opens/19th-open-st-andrews-1879/#leaderboard"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("div", {"class": "final-leaderboard__table"})
rows = table.find_all('div', {'class':"final-leaderboard__row"})
header = list(parse_row(rows[0]))
for row in rows[1:]:
    print(dict(zip(header, list(parse_row(row)))))
```

output

```
{'Name': 'Jamie ANDERSON     Champion Golfer', 'Finish': '1', 'R1': '84', 'R2': '85', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '169', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Andrew KIRKALDY', 'Finish': '2', 'R1': '86', 'R2': '86', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '172', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Jamie ALLAN', 'Finish': '2', 'R1': '88', 'R2': '84', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '172', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'George  PAXTON', 'Finish': '4', 'R1': '89', 'R2': '85', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '174', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Tom KIDD', 'Finish': '5', 'R1': '87', 'R2': '88', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '175', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Bob FERGUSON', 'Finish': '6', 'R1': '89', 'R2': '87', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '176', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'J.O.F. MORRIS', 'Finish': '7', 'R1': '92', 'R2': '87', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '179', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Jack KIRKALDY', 'Finish': '8', 'R1': '92', 'R2': '89', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '181', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'James RENNIE', 'Finish': '8', 'R1': '93', 'R2': '88', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '181', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Willie FERNIE', 'Finish': '8', 'R1': '92', 'R2': '89', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '181', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'David AYTON', 'Finish': '11', 'R1': '95', 'R2': '89', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '184', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Henry LAMB', 'Finish': '11', 'R1': '91', 'R2': '93', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '184', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Tom ARUNDEL', 'Finish': '11', 'R1': '95', 'R2': '89', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '184', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Tom MORRIS SR', 'Finish': '14', 'R1': '92', 'R2': '93', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '185', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'William DOLEMAN', 'Finish': '14', 'R1': '91', 'R2': '94', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '185', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Robert KINSMAN', 'Finish': '14', 'R1': '88', 'R2': '97', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '185', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Bob MARTIN', 'Finish': '17', 'R1': '93', 'R2': '93', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '186', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Ben SAYERS', 'Finish': '18', 'R1': '92', 'R2': '95', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '187', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'David ANDERSON SR', 'Finish': '19', 'R1': '94', 'R2': '94', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '188', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'David CORSTORPHINE', 'Finish': '20', 'R1': '93', 'R2': '96', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '189', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Tom DUNN', 'Finish': '20', 'R1': '90', 'R2': '99', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '189', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Peter PAXTON', 'Finish': '20', 'R1': '99', 'R2': '90', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '189', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': '[A] SMITH', 'Finish': '20', 'R1': '94', 'R2': '95', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '189', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'D. GRANT', 'Finish': '20', 'R1': '95', 'R2': '94', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '189', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Bob DOW', 'Finish': '20', 'R1': '95', 'R2': '94', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '189', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Walter GOURLAY', 'Finish': '20', 'R1': '92', 'R2': '97', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '189', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'A.W. SMITH', 'Finish': '27', 'R1': '91', 'R2': '99', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '190', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Douglas Argyll ROBERTSON', 'Finish': '27', 'R1': '97', 'R2': '93', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '190', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Robert ARMIT', 'Finish': '29', 'R1': '95', 'R2': '96', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '191', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'George  STRATH', 'Finish': '29', 'R1': '97', 'R2': '94', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '191', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'J.H. BLACKWELL', 'Finish': '31', 'R1': '96', 'R2': '96', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '192', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Tom MANZIE', 'Finish': '32', 'R1': '96', 'R2': '97', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '193', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'George LOWE', 'Finish': '33', 'R1': '94', 'R2': '100', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '194', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'G. HONEYMAN', 'Finish': '33', 'R1': '97', 'R2': '97', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '194', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'James FENTON', 'Finish': '35', 'R1': '99', 'R2': '97', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '196', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Robert TAIT', 'Finish': '35', 'R1': '99', 'R2': '97', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '196', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Bob KIRK', 'Finish': '37', 'R1': '99', 'R2': '98', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '197', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Rev. D. LUNDIE', 'Finish': '37', 'R1': '98', 'R2': '99', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '197', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'Fitz BOOTHBY', 'Finish': '39', 'R1': '96', 'R2': '102', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '198', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'J. Thomson WHITE', 'Finish': '40', 'R1': '102', 'R2': '99', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '201', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'James KIRK', 'Finish': '41', 'R1': '105', 'R2': '97', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '202', 'Par': 'M/C'}
{'Name': 'W.H. GOFF', 'Finish': '42', 'R1': '105', 'R2': '99', 'R3': '-', 'R4': '-', 'Total': '204', 'Par': 'M/C'}
```

of course, instead of `dict` you may use other data structure like `namedtuple`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a dictionary , enumerate through your `Rowcontents` and update the dictionary with key as enumerated index(`i`) mod 8 (`i%8`) and value "the text"

```
RowContents = TournamentSoup.findAll("div", {"class": "final-leaderboard__content"})
d={}
for i, RowContent in enumerate(RowContents):
    key = (i)%8
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(' '.join(RowContent.text.strip().split()))

>>> d
{
   0: ['Name','Jamie ANDERSON Champion Golfer','Andrew KIRKALDY','Jamie ALLAN',....]
   1: ['Finish','1','2','2','4',....]
   2: ['R1','84','86','88','89','87',....]
   .......
  7: ['Par','M/C','M/C','M/C','M/C','M/C',.....]
```

if you can use pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
>>> print(df)  

                              Name Finish   R1   R2 R3 R4 Total  Par
1   Jamie ANDERSON Champion Golfer      1   84   85  -  -   169  M/C
2                  Andrew KIRKALDY      2   86   86  -  -   172  M/C
3                      Jamie ALLAN      2   88   84  -  -   172  M/C
4                    George PAXTON      4   89   85  -  -   174  M/C
5                         Tom KIDD      5   87   88  -  -   175  M/C
6                     Bob FERGUSON      6   89   87  -  -   176  M/C
7                    J.O.F. MORRIS      7   92   87  -  -   179  M/C
```

to save a dataframe to csv use [pandas.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
df.to_csv('yourfile.csv', index=False)
```